# closedness and completeness of the space (Analysis 2 by Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Proposition 1.4.12. (Analysis 2 by Tao)

(a) Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $(Y, d|_{Y\times Y})$ be a subspace of $(X,d)$. If $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$ is complete, then $Y$ must be closed in $X$.

(b) Conversely, suppose that $(X, d)$ is a complete metric space, and $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$. Then the subspace $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$ is also complete.

Relative Topology: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, let $Y$ be a subset of $X$, and let $E$ be a subset of $Y$. We say that $E$ is relatively closed with respect to $Y$ if it is closed in the metric space $(Y, d|_{Y\times Y})$.

Attempt:

(a) Every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ is convergent in $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$. Since every convergent sequence is Cauchy, every convergent sequence in $Y$ is convergent in $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$. This implies that $Y$ is closed in $X$ (I do not understand why it is closed in "$X$").

(b) $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$. This implies that every convergent sequence in $Y$ is convergent in $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$. Since every convergent sequence is Cauchy, $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$ is complete. (I do not understand why we need the hypothesis $(X ,d)$.

Comment: (a) You are using the property $A\subset X$ is closed iff every convergent sequence of elements of $A$ has its limit in $A$ (characterization of closedness in metric spaces) (b) Same property here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (a) we have that $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$ is complete and have to show that  $Y$ is closed in $X$. To this end let $(y_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $Y$ with limit $y_0$.

It is clear that $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$. Since  $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$ is complete, there is $z_0 \in Y$ such that $y_n \to z_0.$ Since $(y_n)$ has only one limit, we derive $y_0=z_0 \in Y.$ This shows that $Y$ is closed in $X$.

(b): Now we have that $(X,d)$ is complete and that $Y$ is closed in $X$. Now let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Then $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. $X$ is complete, hence there is $x_0 \in X$ such that $y_n \to x_0$. Since $Y$ is closed, we get $x_0 \in Y.$

hence every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ has a limit in $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little bit confusing about the concept of relative topology. For (a), why did you conclude that $Y$ is closed in "$X$"? What does $X$ actually mean here?

Comment: $Y$ closed in $X$ means that $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$. And that is, what you have to show in (a).